# I can't find the difference between date's

Tags: r

I can't find the difference between the date's, even though I have loaded the "lubridate" package and stick to the syntax.

```
the_election <- read.csv("1622894585_export.csv")

library(lubridate)
mutate(the_election, air_length1 = as.numeric(start_time - end_time, units = "mins"))
```

The above mentioned is the code in R, the "start_time" and "end_time" are the dates. I can't find the difference between the two, for some reason. please help me.

Comment: It's `difftime(start_time, end_time, units = "mins")`.

Comment: Please share the format of your date columns of the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

With `difftime()` you get there

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# no reproducible example - simulated data
df <- data.frame(
     start_time = ymd_hms(c("2021-06-03 08:00:00", "2021-06-04 09:17:23", "2021-06-05 14:54:00"))
    ,end_time   = ymd_hms(c("2021-06-03 08:36:54", "2021-06-04 09:58:03", "2021-06-05 15:12:40"))
) 

# calculate the time difference between dates
#----------------------- set units to minutes in difftime()
df %>% 
mutate( air_lenght1     = difftime(end_time, start_time, units = "min")
       ,air_lenght1_num = as.numeric(air_lenght1))
```

This yields:

```
         start_time            end_time   air_lenght1 air_lenght1_num
1 2021-06-03 08:00:00 2021-06-03 08:36:54 36.90000 mins        36.90000
2 2021-06-04 09:17:23 2021-06-04 09:58:03 40.66667 mins        40.66667
3 2021-06-05 14:54:00 2021-06-05 15:12:40 18.66667 mins        18.66667
```

You can wrap the `as.numeric()` around the `difftime()` call.

Note:

- `difftime()` expects the `end-time` as the first parameter, i.e. time1, for a positive durations.
- with `units = ...` you set the unit of the time period calculation. In other cases you might opt for seconds, hours, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `lubridate` package functions here. I also would like to thank dear @Ray for providing a sample data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Int = interval(start_time, end_time) / minutes(1))

           start_time            end_time      Int
1 2021-06-03 08:00:00 2021-06-03 08:36:54 36.90000
2 2021-06-04 09:17:23 2021-06-04 09:58:03 40.66667
3 2021-06-05 14:54:00 2021-06-05 15:12:40 18.66667
```